# After upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, MySQL server is not starting

Tags: mysql, upgrade

I upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

The process upgraded MySQL 5.7 to 8.0

It instantly started to throw errors in error logs

```
[ERROR] [MY-013379] [Server] Server upgrade started with version 80033, but server upgrade of version 50700 is still pending.
[ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
```

Then I removed MySQL 8.0 and installed 5.7. It started to throw:

```
2023-05-10T09:39:18.573394Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4000!
2023-05-10 12:39:18 0x7fdaa186d740  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140576989566784 in file ut0ut.cc line 921
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
09:39:18 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary or one of
the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built, or misconfigured.
This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68199 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0x55ad17445bab]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x377)[0x55ad16cd0937]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x14420)[0x7fdaa1dc6420]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcb)[0x7fdaa18b500b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x12b)[0x7fdaa1894859]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6adadc)[0x55ad16ca6adc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN2ib5fatalD1Ev+0x66)[0x55ad177f64d6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x12aa42b)[0x55ad178a342b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x12aaa4d)[0x55ad178a3a4d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z6fil_ioRK9IORequestbRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmmPvS8_+0x322)[0x55ad178afc12]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13buf_read_pageRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_t+0xdd)[0x55ad178625bd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16buf_page_get_genRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmP11buf_block_tmPKcmP5mtr_tb+0x465)[0x55ad17834445]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z31trx_rseg_get_n_undo_tablespacesPm+0x14f)[0x55ad177d494f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x11a1a58)[0x55ad1779aa58]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z34innobase_start_or_create_for_mysqlv+0x2e76)[0x55ad1779ee16]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x106da6d)[0x55ad17666a6d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x4f)[0x55ad16d2549f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xc1e3d5)[0x55ad172173d5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z40plugin_register_builtin_and_init_core_sePiPPc+0x1e5)[0x55ad1721a8f5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6d1990)[0x55ad16cca990]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x79e)[0x55ad16ccc05e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0x7fdaa1896083]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_start+0x2a)[0x55ad16cc061a]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Are there any possibilities to fix?

Comment: Please post your complete my.cnf content for analysis.  How much RAM on the server and core/cpu count?